# How to pass value from one php to another without overlaying entire page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I am using a dynamic website constructed with different php includes. I have a particular textbox that lets the user type any name and submits it to the next page.

```
<form action="pages/searchResult.php" method="get">
    <div style="text-align: center"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter first or last name" name="name" class="textbox"/></div>                               
    <div style="text-align: center"><a href="main index.php?page=searchResult"><input type="Submit" value="Search" class="css_button"/></a></div>
</form>
```

The fact that I am using a form already lets the searchResult page overlay everything. I just want it to be loaded into a particular div so that it does not mess with the **header.php** and **footer.php** setup. I want it to not replace everything.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**include ('header.php');**

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**include ('content.php');** [switch case]*(Where I want the searchResult.php to be loaded)*

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**include ('footer.php');**

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: They keyword to google is "Ajax"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using "ajax".Search for "ajax" and it is easy to use.Here it is reference link for you.[Ajax Demo](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/ajax/)

Comment: Thank you friend, i will look it up!